# Logic Apps Do Until Error Http Get Request Parse JSON

Tags: json, httprequest, azure-logic-apps, get-request

In Microsoft Azure Logic Apps, I have a do until loop which loops through a get request until it is completed.  But the HTTP Get request is giving the following error to do with timeout.  It seems that even with 4 retries within 2 minutes, the http get request times out.

> BadRequest. Http request failed: the server did not respond within the
> timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at
> https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits.
>
> ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded.
> 4 retries occurred.

---

> Until Loop Control elaboration

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, is it possible for you to do a video demo on how to install the code? I am new to logic apps.  Maybe a youtube video. Just showing how and where to install your code?